# Right way to order functions and conditions

Tags: bash, function, conditional-statements

I'm writing a bash script to configure an NFS server. I was able to configure the NFS server manually and it's fully functional.
Now I want to reproduce the same steps in a bash script.
I have all the steps and each step, shell command, I put into a bash function.
I then have a main section where I do the function calls, there are 16 functions in total.
In the main section I want to check the function return value, usually just the "$?" value

```
if [ "function_1" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Since there are 16 function calls, where each function call is dependent on the previous function to be successful, the whole thing becomes a bit unwildy

```
if [ "function_1" -eq "0" ]; then
    if [ "function_2" -eq "0" ]; then
        if [ "function_3" -eq "0" ]; then
            if [ "function_..." -eq "0" ]; then
                if [ "function_16" -eq "0" ]; then
```

My question is, is this the right way to structure the program or would it be better not to use functions at all and just do the command validation in the main section

```
chmod -R 0755 $SHARED_FILE_SYSTEM
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure
fi
```

Comment: I'm assuming you just want `if function_1 && function_2 && ... && function 16; then`

Comment: Hi @chepner, thank you for the info. Yes I thought about that. I assume as soon as one function condition fails, like on function_2 the whole process is stopped and returns anon ")" value. How would I know which function call failed. I would like to output an error message to asn installation log so that the user can check which statement/command caused the error

Comment: @user2872898, that's a matter of adding some instrumentation. Have each function set a variable when it starts and there you are -- the value tells you the last one that was run... if, of course, you don't just want to log the whole thing; for my own installers, I run `set -x` with an appropriately informative `PS4`.

Comment: BTW, note that using `$?` is generally a bad practice if all you're going to do is distinguish zero/nonzero for purposes of immediate branching. `if chmod -R 0755 "$SHARED_FILE_SYSTEM"; then echo "Success"; else echo "Failure"` ensures that the branch is done based on the `chmod`, and not disrupted by logging commands or other things that could inadvertently change `$?`.

Comment: ...I also, as an idiom, do something like `chmod 0755 "$SHARED_FILE_SYSTEM" || die "Failure setting permissions for shared filesystem`, with `die` being something like `die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to make a list of the functions and run them in a loop, as demonstrated by this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# ...

config_functions=(
    function_1
    function_2
    # ...
    function_15
    function_16 )

for cfunc in "${config_functions[@]}" ; do
    if "$cfunc" ; then
        printf 'Success: %s\n' "$cfunc"
    else
        printf 'Failure: %s (%d)\n' "$cfunc" "$?"
    fi
done
```

- There's no need to check `$?` explicitly, and [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) will issue a warning if you do it.  See [Shellcheck SC2181](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2181).
- If you want to stop immediately when any function fails, put a `break` or `exit "$?"`, as appropriate, in the 'Failure' branch of the `if`.

This approach also works well if the functions take arguments, but only if the arguments are always the same.  (Just add the arguments to the function invocation in the loop.)  It is less effective if different functions take different arguments.  You could try putting full function invocations in strings in an array, but it's tricky to handle arguments that need to be quoted.

Consider using a configuration management tool such as [Chef](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_(software)), [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)), [Ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible_(software)), or [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(software)) to configure your NFS service.  They have many advantages over scripts.

Comment: Thank you @pjh that's good information. Does this shellcheck, looping over functions, also work with passing inputs to a function.   ``` function check_user () { getent passdw $1     check_user $USER_NAME```, adding thos parameter within the for loop? And yes I'm familiar and have used some of those build/deploy infrastructures. Those require to have an environment where to set it up, ie. chef, ansible. We already have a build/deploy infrastructure tool with a script component where I can add a script and the tool will execute the script on the server it deploys to.

Comment: @user2872898, I've added a paragraph about using this approach with functions that take arguments.  In short: it probably isn't suitable.  Note that [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a static analysis tool for shell code, not something that is used or done in shell code.  It catches a lot of problems in shell code, and helps to improve code quality.

Answer (score 1):

If the functions take arguments (and different functions take different arguments), one way to simplify command validation is to use a function to do it:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

# ...

# Run a configuration command (passed as arguments) and report if it succeeds or
# fails.  Call 'exit' if the command fails.
function doconf
{
    if "$@" ; then
        printf 'Success: %s\n' "$*"
        return 0
    else
        local status=$?
        printf 'Failure: %s (%d)\n' "$*" "$status"
        exit "$status"
    fi
}

doconf function_1 arg1
doconf function_2 arg2a arg2b
# ...
doconf function_15 arg15a arg15b arg15c arg15d
doconf function_16 arg16a arg16b arg16c
```

If you don't want the program to exit immediately when a function fails, you can trap the `exit` done by `doconf` by putting the `doconf` calls in subshell:

```
# ...

(
    doconf function_1 arg1
    doconf function_2 arg2a arg2b
    # ...
    doconf function_15 arg15a arg15b arg15c arg15d
    doconf function_16 arg16a arg16b arg16c
)

# Program execution continues here, even if a `doconf` exits
# ...
```

- `doconf` isn't a great name.  You might want to change it.
- `doconf` should have a check to ensure that at least one argument (the command name) is provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's an anti-pattern to check `$?`. It's better to just test the command directly in the `if` statement:

```
if cmd; then
    ...
fi
```

Having explicit `if` checks and error messages is unwieldy. A common pattern to avoid it is to simply exit if a command fails and rely on the command to print its own error message. You don't need to print anything yourself. Then you can use `|| return` or `|| exit` to bail out when a command fails, where `a || b` is shorthand for `if ! a; then b; fi`.

```
function_1 || exit
function_2 || exit
function_3 || exit
...
```

Note that `return` and `exit` will automatically use `$?`.

If you want to exit when any command fails, an even easier option is to enable the `errexit` flag with `set -e`. Do that and the shell will automatically exit the script without you having to insert tedious checks.

```
set -e

function_1
function_2
function_3
...
```